# toolbar.inflateMenu() doesn't work in the second call?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

**Background :** I need to `Customize` my `ToolBar` by `Fragment` so I use `setCustomToolBarForFragment` method to achieve that (the problem is occurred inside Fragment B with `Fragment` A -> `Fragment` B)

**Problem :** The first time `Fragment` B is created `setCustomToolBarForFragment` work as expected but in the second time it doesn't.

**Fragment B first creation (A->B):**

[image]

**Fragment B second creation (A->B)**

[image]

**setCustomToolBarForFragment [code]** :

```
 private void setCustomToolBarForFragment() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // CustomView
    View customToolBar =
        getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toolbar_custom_view, null);
    ((TextView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.tool_bat_title)).setText("Filter Criteria");
    ((ImageView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.icon_left)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    ((ImageView) customToolBar.findViewById(R.id.icon_right)).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    toolbar.removeAllViews();
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_event_detail);
    toolbar.addView(customToolBar);
  }
```

**Note :** `setCustomToolBarForFragment` called from `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Have you serHasOptionMenu(true)

Comment: @prathamkesarkar yes I did

Comment: If u have set the menu then why are you inflating your menu here and not onCreateMenu

Comment: @prathamkesarkar because am using `ToolBar` with customview

Comment: I have the same Issue! Have you resolved this? @Abdellah

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your method `setCustomToolBarForFragment()` in `onResume()` or in `onCreate()` or `onCreatView()` of your fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCustomToolBarForFragment();

}
```

The reason for your problem is `onActivityCreated()`As the name states, this is called after the Activity's `onCreate()` has completed.

So I think its not calling your Ui changes when your resuming your fragment.

Comment: Nope .. `onActivityCreated` is called every time the Fragment is created also it work in the first call

Answer (score 0):

The toolbar has
`private ActionMenuView mMenuView` for the menu. And when you call `.inflateMenu()`, toolbar calls internally `ensureMenuView()`, which creates the menuView if NOT already created and adds the view:

```
private void ensureMenuView() {
    if (mMenuView == null) {
        mMenuView = new ActionMenuView(getContext());
       .........
        addSystemView(mMenuView, false);
    }
}
```

When you call `toolbar.removeAllViews()`, the toolbar removes the mMenuView but doesn't make it null. So the next time when you call `inflateMenu()`, the menuView is already created and is not added again to toolbar. You have to find a different way without using `removeAllViews()`;